# download files from AWS S3 bucket in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download million of files from S3 bucket which will take more than a week to be downloaded one by one - any way/ any command to download those files in parallel using shell script ?

Thanks,

Comment: How big are the files? Is the limitation the total amount of data to be transferred, or the overhead of downloading many small files?

Answer (score 3):

**AWS CLI**

You can certainly issue `GetObject` requests in parallel. In fact, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) does exactly that when transferring files, so that it can take advantage of available bandwidth. The `aws s3 sync` command will transfer the content in parallel.

See: [AWS CLI S3 Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

If your bucket has a large number of objects, it can take a long time to list the contents of the bucket. Therefore, you might want to `sync` the bucket by prefix (folder) rather than trying it all at once.

**AWS DataSync**

You might instead want to use [AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/what-is-datasync.html):

> AWS DataSync is an online data transfer service that simplifies, automates, and accelerates copying large amounts of data to and from AWS storage services over the internet or AWS Direct Connect... Move active datasets rapidly over the network into Amazon S3, Amazon EFS, or Amazon FSx for Windows File Server. DataSync includes automatic encryption and data integrity validation to help make sure that your data arrives securely, intact, and ready to use.

DataSync uses a protocol that takes full advantage of available bandwidth and will manage the parallel downloading of content. A fee of `$0.0125 per GB` applies.

**AWS Snowball**

Another option is to use [AWS Snowcone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/snowcone-guide/snowcone-what-is-snowcone.html) (8TB) or [AWS Snowball](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/whatissnowball.html) (50TB or 80TB), which are physical devices that you can pre-load with content from S3 and have it shipped to your location. You then connect it to your network and download the data. (It works in reverse too, for uploading bulk data to Amazon S3).